# What are permanents?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are the specific types of permanents in the game? Are lands included in permanents?

Comment: Could you please try to put actual questions in the title, and when possible, give a bit more background about why you're asking questions? That'll make it a lot easier for people to answer. (It does also help if you upvote and accept answers, or comment if anything's unclear, so that people know for sure if they're covering what you wanted to know.)

Answer (score 10):

The [Basic Rulebook](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf) answers this question.

> **permanent**—Lands, creatures, artifacts,
>   enchantments, and planeswalkers are
>   permanents. They enter the battlefield after you
>   cast them. Token creatures are also permanents.
>   Instants and sorceries are not permanents. They
>   go to the graveyard after they resolve.

Answer (score 7):

A permanent is any card or token on the battlefield. This includes lands, creatures, artifacts, enchantments, and planeswalkers.

Note that they have to actually be on the battlefield to be permanents. For example, a creature card on the battlefield is a permanent, though it's usually just referred to as a creature - the "permanent is implied". If it's on the stack, in the process of being cast, it's a creature *spell*, not a permanent. And if it's elsewhere like in your hand or graveyard, it's just a creature *card*, still not a permanent.